# How optimize my code ? I mean for loop and if statement javascript

Tags: javascript

Problem:

> Given an array of bird sightings where every element represents a bird type id, determine the id of the most frequently sighted type. If more than 1 type has been spotted that maximum amount, return the smallest of their ids.

Suppose that we have 1000 of numbers, how can I optimize my code be more faster? This is a code challenge for hackerrank but I don't know how to optimize it.

```js
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4];

function migratoryBirds(arr) {
  let largest = 1; // We start with number one because is the first number
  // into the array
  let counter = 1; // the first counter is one so we equal to largest.
  let type = 0; // it is the current largest number 

  arr.sort(); // [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
  // console.log(arr.sort()) 
  let i;
  let l = arr.length;

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    // console.log(arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i]), arr.indexOf(arr[i]) , 1)
    // Here we are looking how many times the number exist in the array
    // and summing one to give the real number because the rest give us 
    // just one less number.
    largest = (arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i]) - arr.indexOf(arr[i])) + 1; 
    
    // if largest (the large of the number into the array) greater apply code below.
    if (largest > counter) {
      counter = largest;
      type = arr[i];
    }
  }

return type;
};

console.log(migratoryBirds(arr2));
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in `O(n)`. (Your current approach is `O(n ^ 2)` due to the nested loop - and the `.sort` is `O(n log n)`).

Use an object indexed by `arr` number, whose values are the number of times that value has been found. For example

```
[1, 2, 2, 2]
```

will turn into

```
{
  1: 1,
  2: 3
}
```

After that's done, find the largest value in the object's values by passing to `Math.max`, then iterate over the entries and find the first key with that value.

Using an object here will also help with the side requirement to return the lowest ID in case multiple entries with the largest value exist. (Object keys that are array indicies like 1, 2, etc, are always ordered in ascending numeric order)

```js
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4];

function migratoryBirds(arr) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const num of arr) {
    obj[num] = (obj[num] || 0) + 1;
  }
  const max = Math.max(...Object.values(obj));
  return Number(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .find(entry => entry[1] === max)
      [0] // extract key from entry
  );
};

console.log(migratoryBirds(arr2));
```

In this case, the array items are guaranteed to be from 1 to 5, but if the problem was different and there could be many different array items, you can reduce the complexity by turning the final part into a single iteration [with Kaiido's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432199/how-optimize-my-code-i-mean-for-loop-and-if-statement-javascript/66432250?noredirect=1#comment117444748_66432250) of:

```
const max_entry = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((max, entry) => {
    return max[1] >= entry[1] ? max : entry;
  },
  [, 0]
);
return max_entry[0];
```

Comment: In case there can be many various entries, a single reduce might even be better, both to avoid looping twice through the values + entries and to avoid a max-argument call (`const max_entry = Object.entries(obj).reduce((max, entry) => { return max[1] >= entry[1] ? max : entry; }, [,-Infinity]); return max_entry[0];`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that help me to understand about big O notation. Also thanks for the corrections and comments.

Comment: @Erick I saw the unaccept, was there an issue with the answer?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry I don't why someone closed the question and give me -1 for opinion-based I don't know why. And I try to fix it but I don't know what to do.